# React-native - Error on deploy app to xcode - directory not found for option '-L-L/Users/...'

Tags: react-native

I have a problem on deploy my app to xcode after run command below:

```
pod install
```

After run this command, dependencies was installed correctly:
[image]

When I tried to compile and deploy again, I had the several erros like this:

```
1) Target 'XXX' (project 'XXX') has copy command from '/Users/XXX/Documents/projects/react-native/tasks/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Zocial.ttf' to '/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-bbklwsxeibuqhtduldwfhgorkgcg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XXX.app/Zocial.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'XXX' (project 'XXX'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
```

To fix it, I change build system of xcode:
[image]

But now, I have the following issue:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L-L/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-bbklwsxeibuqhtduldwfhgorkgcg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CocoaAsyncSocket'
ld: library not found for -lCocoaAsyncSocket
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with this link:
https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support/issues/36

[image]